# Is there a reason why R functions contour and image (both graphics package) use levels/breaks differently?

Tags: r, contour, levelplot

I think the Title of this question says it all - I can't understand why two functions from the same package (`graphics`) would treat intervals differently. The `image` function uses the breaks argument to define levels, and the function `cut` assigns colors:

> "If `breaks` is specified then `zlim` is unused and the algorithm used follows `cut`, so intervals are closed on the right and open on the left except for the lowest interval which is closed at both ends.*"

This means that e.g. if breaks are defined as `c(0,100,150,170,190,200)`, a value of `150` would be assigned to the interval 100 < x <= 150:

```
Levels: (0,100] (100,150] (150,170] (170,190] (190,200]
```

As an example, the plot below shows two possible image plots with contours overlayed. Only when slightly lower breaks are used, do the color intervals match-up with the contours:

```
pal=colorRampPalette(c("green", "cyan", "yellow", "red", "pink"), space="rgb")
breaks <- c(0,100, 150, 170, 190, 200)
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(0.2,0.1,3,0.1))

image(seq(dim(volcano)[1]), seq(dim(volcano)[2]), volcano, col=pal(length(breaks)-1), breaks=breaks, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="")
contour(seq(dim(volcano)[1]), seq(dim(volcano)[2]), volcano, levels=breaks, add=TRUE)
box()
mtext("image(breaks=breaks)\ncontour(levels=breaks)", side=3, line=0.5)

image(seq(dim(volcano)[1]), seq(dim(volcano)[2]), volcano, col=pal(length(breaks)-1), breaks=breaks-0.01, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="")
contour(seq(dim(volcano)[1]), seq(dim(volcano)[2]), volcano, levels=breaks, add=TRUE)
box()
mtext("image(breaks=breaks-0.01)\ncontour(levels=breaks)", side=3, line=0.5)
```

[image]

So, can anyone tell me if there is a reason for this mismatch, or a possibly better workaround than the one that I have shown?

Comment: I think that have to do with the fact that the locus for value 150 (for instance) is not a line but an area (see what happens when you draw `image(seq(dim(volcano)[1]), seq(dim(volcano)[2]),volcano, col=pal(3), breaks=c(0,150-1e-5,150+1e-5,max(volcano)))`): `contour` delimits with a line, so it depends probably on where the algorithm decides to draw the line when faced with that case. I tried to look at the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/library/graphics/src/plot3d.c#L1845) but i don't really know enough C to understand it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Oh please do explain! I don't know the reference. I'm not Russian, but I'm confused...

Comment: @Marcinthebox  It was a joke based on the fact that some locales (England or USA, I forget) removed all their street signs during WW2 on the theory that residents knew where they were but bad-guy spies would get lost.  During the Cold War, this led to a variety of jokes along the lines of "that's really confusing-why was it done that way?" "to confuse the spies..."